# how to add class smoothscroll to a link defined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, addclass, smoothing

I have a down button div that I want to have the smoothScroll class added to so that when it is clicked, the smooth scrolling happens before it jumps to the link that is attached to it in the JS file. I'm just not sure how to make the addClass run before the window.location everytime I try it it breaks.

HTML:

```
<div id="downButton">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
  $(function() {
  // This will select everything with the class smoothScroll
  // This should prevent problems with carousel, scrollspy, etc...
    $('.smoothScroll').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, 1000); // The number here represents the speed of the scroll in milliseconds
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  });

 $('#downButton').click(function () {
    window.location = '#aboutSection';
 });
```

Comment: I don't see an 'addClass' function. To what are you trying add the 'smoothScroll' class? Also, your $('#downButton').click event handler should be inside your $(function(){ so that the click event doesn't try to bind to the button before the button is actually loaded to the DOM.

Comment: It looks as if you have 2 methods essentially doing the same thing. the $('#downButton').click method moves the window to the #aboutSection. Also, if you're trying to add the 'smoothScroll' class to the #downButton, Then you have a new event handler that is running on the same click. If the point is to smoothly scroll to #aboutSection when the down arrow is clicked you don't need to add the 'smoothScroll' class. Just handle it all in the $(#downButton).click event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There are many other links on the page that are using the smoothScroll class to go to their destinations. Is the most efficient way to handle the smooth Scroll in the #downButton or is it to add the class to the #downButton.click?

Comment: If the former, please explain more I am not sure i see what you mean.

Comment: Are the other links that trigger this smoothScroll also DIV tags with click events added to them or are they ANCHOR tags with HREF attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make this quickly work would be like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#downButton').click(function () {
        var target = $('#aboutSection');
        $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
              }, 1000);
     }); 
});
```

if you'd like to make it more re-usable I'd do it this way:

HTML:

```
<div id="downButton" class="scrollme" data-goto="#aboutSection">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
```

Then the javascript would be:

```
$(function() {
  $('.scrollme').click(function(){
      scrollme(this);
  });
});

function scrollme(el){
    var id = $(el).data('target');
    var $target = $('#' + id);
    console.log($target.length)
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

Then you just have to add a class of scrollme to any element with a data-target attribute with the id of the element to which to scroll.